# Powershell -Filter not accepting two conditions

Tags: powershell, wmi, user-accounts

I have this command

```
$remoteuserlist = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount `
-filter "LocalAccount =True" –computername $PC -verbose
```

that I am running to get a list of local accounts on a machine. I would also like to exclude the guest account from my list. so I tried something like this

```
$remoteuserlist = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount `
-filter {LocalAccount =True -and Name -ne "Guest" –computername $PC -verbose}
```

but I get an invalid query error. Can someone explain my presumably blindingly obvious error?

Thanks

Comment: The filter is a WMI query but the `-not ...` bit of that query looks like powershell code. Presumably that would be the problem, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$remoteuserlist = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -filter {LocalAccount = "True" and Name != "Guest"} –computername $PC -verbose
```

1. You were mixing WMI syntax and PowerShell syntax
2. The brackets encompassing the filter were around the other parameters of `Get-WmiObject`

Answer (score 2):

The WQL "not equal" operator is != or <>.

[WQL Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394605(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of old VBScript WMI queries laying around you can use the Get-WMIObject -Query param to reuse them.

```
$remoteuserlist = Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount WHERE LocalAccount = 'True' and Name != 'Guest'" –computername $PC -verbose
```

Not groundbreaking but it can help if you don't want to rewrite queries.